# CSS issue in the Mat-Table area

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I used CSS to adjust the width of the columns.
Now I have the problem that my columns exceed the defined mat-table. Do you have an idea how to solve it?

[image: Mat-Table]

```
<div class="content-wrapper mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Data Table -->
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [class.isMobile]="isMobile">
        ...
      </mat-table>
</div>
  </div>
```

```
.table-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mat-row#mat-row-mobile {
  min-height: 30px;
}

.mat-column-1, .mat-column-2, .mat-column-3, .mat-column-4, .mat-column-5, .mat-column-6, .mat-column-7, .mat-column-8, .mat-column-9, .mat-column-10, .mat-column-11, .mat-column-12 {
  flex: 0 0 10% !important;
  min-width: 110px !important;
}

.mat-column-note {
  flex: 0 0 12% !important;
  min-width: 170px !important;
}

.mat-column-assignment {
  flex: 0 0 17% !important;
  min-width: 230px !important;
}
```

Comment: can you provide an image of whats really happening?

Comment: image is in. I just edited the question.

Comment: Will need your html code too. To identify which `<div>` has got which class in short (their arrangements)

Comment: Ok.Try changing `position = "relative"` to  `position = "absolute"` to the class `.table-wrapper`

Comment: I have and it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the class for the contents that are going out?

Comment: The class is .mat-table

Comment: Please try appliying the `position = "absolute"` to it,because this makes the element fit into its parent element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211060/discussion-between-anyanx-and-kunal-raut).

Comment: I have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the calculations. For example

```
.mat-column-1, .mat-column-2, .mat-column-3, ... , .mat-column-12 {
   flex: 0 0 10% !important; // this equals to 120% 
   min-width: 110px !important; // this equals to 1320px. Be carefull. Please ask yourself "What happens if my screen is narrower?" Then width in fixed units is a problem
}
```

Some reading about CSS LENGTHS. [css lengths](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

You can try restricting

```
.mat-column-kag {
  flex: 0 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 90px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mat-column-name{
  flex: 0 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 200px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mat-column-accountNumber
.mat-column-1,
.mat-column-2,
.mat-column-3,
.mat-column-4,
.mat-column-5,
.mat-column-6,
.mat-column-7,
.mat-column-8,
.mat-column-9,
.mat-column-10,
.mat-column-11,
.mat-column-12,
{
     flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 290px) / 13) !important;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Note: Also i added box-sizing to all your custom width columns because padding length is taken into account if this property is not set, this adds extra length.

Read more about box sizing here [box-sizing: border-box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)